# Reducing latency with Google app engine search api

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

Let's say we are building a product catalog using Google app engine and trying to incorporate full text search. What are the factors to consider to guarantee latency in 200 ms .

As the document index grows , how do you configure app engine to linearly scale without compromising latency.

Neo